# Is it possible to create a table on a linked server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to create a table on a linked server?

Answer (score 21):

```
exec

('CREATE TABLE DatabaseName.dbo.TableName
(
  column1 datatype,
  column2 datatype,
  column3 datatype
)') at [LinkedServer]
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Failed with
Msg 7411, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Server 'MyLinkedServer' is not configured for RPC.

Comment: Old issue, but as no one replied, here is the solution to the error: "'MyLinkedServer' is not configured for RPC".

Comment: The exec solution does not send the "Create table" statement to the linked server as a SQL statement. It sends it as a string which in turn is executed as a procedure on the remote server. The RPC error comes because the linked server-connection pr. default does not allow you to execute procedures remote. To solve this: Open the properites on the linked server. On the [Server Options] page, set RPC and RPC Out options as true. I'm adding a post with the screen shot.

Answer (score 4):

The solution from Arpit works fine.

```
exec

('CREATE TABLE DatabaseName.dbo.TableName
(
  column1 datatype,
  column2 datatype,
  column3 datatype
)') at [LinkedServer];
go
```

How ever, when you get the error "Msg 7411, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Server 'MyLinkedServer' is not configured for RPC." you need to change the RPC-parameters on the linked server connection. As default RPC is set to false. It needs to be set to true.

[image: Linked server options]

This allows you to run procedures on the linked server.
You must allow this because the solution does not send the "Create table" statement as a SQL command to the linked server. It sends the statement as a string which in turn is executed as a procedure on the remote server.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SQL Server Management Studio and the SQLCMD mode:

```
-- To enable "SQLCMD mode" in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS):
-- In the menu toolbar: Query > SQLCMD mode

:setvar LinkedServer "YourLinkedServerNameHere"
:setvar DestinationDb "YourDestinationDatabaseNameHere"
GO

EXEC ('
CREATE TABLE $(DestinationDb).dbo.YourTableNameHere (
    [Field1] INT NOT NULL,
    [Field2] INT NOT NULL
)
') AT $(LinkedServer)
GO

EXEC ('DROP TABLE $(DestinationDb).dbo.YourTableNameHere') AT $(LinkedServer)
GO
```

Comment: This failed for me with: Msg 7411, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Server 'MyLinkedServer' is not configured for RPC.